# Permutation matrix notation

Tags: matrices

What is the official notation (and the source of the notation) of the following permutations matrices (one shift left of identity matrix):

For $n=2$

$P = \left(\begin{matrix}0 & 1\\ 1&0\end{matrix}\right)$

For $n=3$

$P = \left(\begin{matrix}0 & 0 & 1\\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0\end{matrix}\right)$

Comment: You may borrow the notations from permutation group https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_group

Comment: $P$ stands for Permutation, I think. Unfortunately, somtimes $P$ stands for other matrices as well, i.e., for alternating sign matrices: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_sign_matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Horn and Johnson in their book on Matrix Analysis use the same $P$. Look at this:

http://books.google.de/books?id=LeuNXB2bl5EC&pg=PA165&lpg=PA165&dq=Horn+and+Johnson+matrix+analysis++permutation+matrix&source=bl&ots=SmGty8svBa&sig=BruvJ-h7lRg3BQ5t98UIqfetiu8&hl=fr&sa=X&ei=xFMoUq28FIqztAbj1oFY&ved=0CIEBEOgBMAg#v=onepage&q=Horn%20and%20Johnson%20matrix%20analysis%20%20permutation%20matrix&f=false